# What happens behind the scenes in 'Q' complex database?

Tags: django, database

I am trying to write a query that is as efficient as possible. Here is my problem: 
Assume I have 10 teachers objects, and each teacher has a 100 test objects (The test is related to the teacher by OneToOne relation). I have the unique slug of the each test, and so I can just look it up like this:

`CreateTest.objects.filter(slug__iexact= slug_name)`

But, this way seems very inefficient because Django will look for every test that has been created, and there is 1000 of them out there because there are 10 teachers. Instead, I am trying to do something like this:

`teacher=TeacherUser.objects.filter(user__username__iexact=self.request.user)
teacher_test = teacher.createtest_set.filter(slug__iexact=slug_name)`

Now, it is getting all the tests from a specific user, and then it is searching for that test that is needed. 
I want to write that same thing using 'Q'. I thought about writing this:

`CreateTest.objects.filter(teacher__user__username=self.request.user,
 slug__iexact=self.kwargs['slug'])`

But, for some reason, I think that this is not doing what I want. It is checking if the teacher is the same, and the slug is the same. I want it first to get all the tests for a specific teacher. After that I wanted to query the test from only from that list. Any ideas if I doing what I want?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set the relationship between the teacher and tests to be OneToMany rather than OneToOne based on your description:

```
class CreateTest(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(TeacherUser)
```

If you've already done that, then you've tried a couple of viable options, namely getting the test directly from the slug or pk which should be efficient if your table is indexed by the slug and pk.

One issue you seem to be confusing is that you are using `.filter` to return an instance, when you should be using `.get`.

`.filter` returns another QuerySet, not an instance.

Your last attempt should look like this:

```
CreateTest.objects.filter(
    teacher__user=self.request.user,
    slug__iexact=self.kwargs['slug']
)
```

You are trying to compare the username with the user object which won't work

Hope you get it going